# Java generic specification

Tags: java, generics

Having trouble figuring out how to express this in java generics. I want to create a method that will create some test data - in this case, pass in a collection type and a value type and return an example of that - e.g.

```
generateSampleCollection(HashSet.class, String.class) -> returns a HashSet<String>
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to express this with generics. For example:

```
public static <T extends Collection<E>, E> T<E> generateSampleCollection(Class<T> t, Class<E> i) {... }
```

fails with the error "The type T is not generic". Anyone know how to do this? Seems like it should be do-able but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way in generics to express that a type represented by a type variable has a (or many) type parameter(s).

So you cannot do what you want. The most you can do is

```
public static <T extends Collection<E> /* and the E doesn't change anything */, E> T generateSampleCollection(
        Class<T> t, Class<E> i) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return null; // actually return an instance of type T
}
```

and cast the return value.